# Defining custom state list

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

When I attach `Interactable` component to my prefab, I can choose one (or more) of 4 state blueprints, such as `DefaultInteractableStates.asset`. Although it contains 4 defined states, I would need to remove "Default state" from that. Is there a way I could define my own list of states? I can see the `-` button to remove state, but the asset is read-only, so I cannot edit it.
[image: State list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like MRTK

=> in general all the original profile assets are read-only protected.

You always need to make a **copy**/**clone** of whatever profile you want to change and edit the copy instead and assign the copy to your profiles.

Also see [How to configure Interactable](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/ux-building-blocks/interactable?view=mrtkunity-2021-05#how-to-configure-interactable).

Comment: Thank you! I was a little bit confused about the documentation of how can I clone the state because I could not see it in profile settings. But it was just as easy as right-clicking in the folder structure "Create > Mixed Reality > Toolkit > State"